# how do I connect to mqtt.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt

I need to connect my mqtt-spy client to mqtt.googleapis.com with rsa_public.pem and root.ca
What configuration parameters should be used?.

I attempted many possible combinations of options none worked.

Comment: Just saying "I tried a load of stuff" isn't helpful, you need to clearly explain what you actually tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I have configured my device  and gateway.. as prescribed by google documents. 
Also have generated key pair using
 openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out rsa_private.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
 openssl rsa -in rsa_private.pem -pubout -out rsa_public.pem
 
I basically want the functionality you have implemented in the 
 'node-red-contrib-googlehome' without depending on the services hosted within your servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That endpoint is an MQTT bridge used by Cloud IoT. It is extensively documented and I encourage you to review the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge

It's possible Google applies constraints to the bridge to focus its use to client devices interacting with Cloud IoT so it may not present with 100% fidelity as an MQTT broker but, you *should* be able to configure mqtt-spy to connect to it as long as you're able to present as a device with certs.